# Is there a way to get a generic call to any UIButton's method selector?

Tags: swift, uibutton, analytics, swizzle

I've recently come across the technique of swizzling. It looks like it's not a super common practice to use and I can understand the drawbacks I keep seeing listed for it. But as it's a thing that we can use in swift, I was hoping I could throw together something in a playground or practice project.

The idea I had was to use swizzling for analytics purposes. At this point, just to print off what the user is actually doing. I can't really think of interactions the user might make besides tapping buttons on their screen. I figure, I might be able to swizzle `UITapGestureRecognizer` and make it run a function tracking tap position, etc. But that's too much information for me. I just want to know when a button is tapped. So I think the only thing I need to swizzle is the `UIButton`. But we set the selector for UIButtons or we set them up as `IBActions`.

So my question is, Is there a way to get a generic call to any button's method selector? That way, I can swizzle the button in one place. Make it run the analytics and then call the primary function all without actually changing my code in my `UIViewController` classes directly.

I would post my attempts, but their rather sensical and I couldn't get anything to even run.

Is this a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try swizzling [`sendAction(_:to:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618237-sendaction) in `UIControl`. `UIControl` calls this whenever an event happens for every target-action pair.

```
extension UIControl {
    // call this at an early point in your app lifecycle
    static func swizzle() {
        if let originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIControl.self, #selector(sendAction(_:to:for:))),
           let swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(UIControl.self, #selector(swizzled_sendAction)) {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
        }
    }
    
    @objc func swizzled_sendAction(_ action: Selector,
                                   to target: Any?,
                                   for event: UIEvent?) {
        swizzled_sendAction(action, to: target, for: event)
        if self is UIButton {
            // do some analytics things
        }
    }
}
```

Caveats:

Since this method is called for every target-action pair, this means that this only works if all your buttons have exactly one target-action pair, and only for the event `touchUpInside` (a "tap"). In other words, for each button, you only call `addTarget` once, or add one connection in the storyboard for `touchUpInside`.

If a button does not have any target-action pairs, then tapping it does nothing. The swizzled method will not be called.

If a button has multiple target-action pairs for `touchUpInside`, then tapping it would cause the swizzled method to be called multiple times.

If a button has target-action pairs for events other than `touchUpInside`, then triggering those events would also cause the swizzled method to be called, though this can be prevented to an extent if you carefully check the `UIEvent` parameter.

To be honest, I would rather just subclass `UIButton`, instead of swizzling. Make a subclass that does something like this upon its creation:

```
addTarget(self, action: #selector(doAnalytics), for: .touchUpInside)

...

@objc func doAnalytics() {
    // ...
}
```